# How Do I Test User and Pwd HTTP Authentication NTLM in Powershell

Tags: powershell

i Used Below Code For Basic Authentication...
Now I don't know How To Authentication NTLM Mode...

```
    $url = Read-Host "url: "
    $u = Read-Host "Username: "
    $p = Read-Host "Password: "
    $aggregate = "$u"+":"+$p
    $encode = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("$aggregate"))
    $headreq = "Basic $encode"
    $headers = @{ Authorization = $headreq }
    $httpreq = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -Headers $headers -Method GET -ErrorAction Stop
```

Comment: Construct a `[pscredential]` object from the username/password, then pass that as an argument to `Invoke-WebRequest`'s `-Credentials` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Construct a `[pscredential]` object from the username/password, then pass that as an argument to `Invoke-WebRequest`'s `-Credentials` parameter:

```
$creds = [pscredential]::new($u, ($p |ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlaintext -Force))
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method GET -Credentials $creds
```

`Invoke-WebRequest` will automatically figure out whether the server supports NTLM based on the initial response headers .

Comment: if username and password it's true... what is response and Status Code? Status Code 200?